# Power BI : DAX : Count number of occurrences in measured column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with 2 columns: Contact and Account_id. One contact can have multiple accounts.

In Power BI: I have created a measure 'Compte de Account', that counts the number of accounts related to a specific Contact using DAX.

`Compte de Account  = CALCULATE(COUNT('Rapport globale'[AccountId]))`

Is it possible to count the count of measured column (Compte de Account) in ascending order as mentioned in the screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you bring table data in order to better solve your problem

Comment: change your measure to calculated columns and then create a measure for  count

Comment: alternatively change your measure to calculated table and then create a measure for count

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `Rank = RANKX(ALL('Rapport globale'[Contact]),[Compte de Account],,DESC,Dense)`

[image: Sample data]

The most important part of getting RANK to work is the ALL( ) function. The row context will limit the values of Contact to the current row value, and ALL removes the row context so you can RANK all contacts, not just the contact on the current row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is about Frequency, not Ranking. Commenter @rf1991 was on the right track when he said to change your measure to a calculated column. You essentially want to make this value a dimension on which you can report.

First, create this calculated column.

```
Compte de Account Column = CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Rapport globale'[AccountId]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Rapport globale','Rapport globale'[Contact])
)
```

Next, create your frequency measure.

```
Compte de Account Frequency = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
                SUMMARIZE('Rapport globale','Rapport globale'[Compte de Account Column]),
                "@freq",DISTINCTCOUNT('Rapport globale'[Contact])
        ),
        [@freq]),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Rapport globale'[Contact])
)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Power bi, we can choose a column, and then we can sort the column in ascending order or descending order by using `RANKX()` in measure.